Make a WHERE clause Non-Sargable and remove ISNULL
Is there a better way to represent this WHERE clause so is does not use the Non-SARGable funtion ISNULL?
    1=1
    AND ISNULL([TABLE_NAME_1].[FIELD_NAME_1], -1) <> ISNULL([TABLE_NAME_2].[FIELD_NAME_1], -1)
     OR ISNULL([TABLE_NAME_1].[FIELD_NAME_2], -1) <> ISNULL([TABLE_NAME_2].[FIELD_NAME_2], -1)

This is an update statement which compares table 1 to table 2 and only updated where there is a difference
TABLE 1 represents a working table which is updated daily
TABLE 2 represents a final table which users report against

Please read How To Make A Good Example and improve your question as explained.

In Azure or SQL2022 use IS DISTINCT FROM. In older versions use (t1.FIELD_NAME_1 IS NULL AND t2.FIELD_NAME_1 IS NOT NULL OR t1.FIELD_NAME_1 IS NOT NULL AND t2.FIELD_NAME_1 IS NULL OR t1.FIELD_NAME_1 <> t2.FIELD_NAME_1)

Which dbms are you using?

You have OR, so i doubt it will be sargable anyway. Since you're doing update, you should at least have PK fields in your JOIN, so this shouldn't be a problem anyway
